# SQL Server, Filter by using selective columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite

It looks simple but I need this. I have a table tbl(col1,col2,col3). I want to search the table in a procedure in a way as when I pass value for only col1, query should only consider the value of col1 in where clause. Similarly when I pass value for col1 and col2 it should only consider these two columns in where clause and ignore col3. 
I want to use only a single select query e.g

```
'select * from tbl where col1=@col1 and col2=@col2 and col3=@col3'
```

My original proc is:

```
create proc GetProdData
@source nvarchar(20),
@subsource nvarchar(20)
as
begin
select * From ProductionData 
where Source=@source and SubSource=@subsource
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have indexes, the more efficient way is to generate dynamic SQL.

Otherwise:

```
where (col1 = @col1 or @col1 is null) and
      (col2 = @col2 or @col2 is null) and
      (col3 = @col3 or @col3 is null)
```

Comment: @IkramKhan - Show your procedure definition. It ought to work fine as long as you aren't setting these parameters to something other than null somewhere.

Comment: I have edited the question and posted the original proc. @MartinSmith

Comment: thnku... now its working after a simple modification :)